# Canonical correlation using spss

Tags: correlation, spss, manova, canonical-correlation

I wanted to prove the correlation between 8 variables. I used spss MANOVA

> MANOVA S K A E  WITH D AC C AS / discrim all alpha(1) / print=sig(eigen dim).

But I don't get the canonical correlation all I get is the regression analysis  and I get the following warning:

> The WITHIN CELLS error matrix is SINGULAR. These variables are LINEARLY DEPENDENT on preceding ones ..  E      Multivariate tests will be skipped.

Can anyone please explain to me why I don't have the correlation. Does this mean that there isn't any canonical correlation? If thats the case, is there any other kind of correlation that might be efficient for my data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the MANOVA syntax, but the STATS CANCORR extension command computes canonical correlations.  OVERALS, in the Categories option, computes nonlinear canonical correlations.